# Cache entire page with full querystring

Tags: caching, varnish

I need Varnish to cache a page with varying querystrings. I want to cache each page call with each full querystring permutation for at least an hour.

For example:

- example.com/test?product=socks&color=blue
- example.com/test?product=socks&color=green

*Note: I'm not trying to remove or sort the querystring parameters, I'm trying to keep them.*

Comment: What is your concrete question. This is basically what Varnish does. Set the Cache-Control header to max-age=3600 in your backend to tell Varnish to cache for one hour.

Comment: I did not configure the Varnish 3.x instance I'm debugging. And I see every version of the querystring register as a MISS. So now I must try default VCL config on another box.